# java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1

Tags: java, bluetooth

I am connecting to a UA-767PBT blood pressure monitor through my Android application. However, although it takes the pressure and appears in the log, the values wont appear on my application. Instead the following error appears:

```
java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
```

How do I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], the exception is useless but may help when paired with your code.

Comment: The peer has closed the connection. Reconnect.